# Can I represent a rational symbolic value like a decimal approximation?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

For example, I have the symbolic value which is 's+5/2'. Is there a way to display it like 's+2.5'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html).  Simply take your symbolic expression and use the `vpa` function to facilitate the conversion.  `vpa` evaluates each term in the symbolic expression and converts each value to using up to 32 significant digits whenever possible.  You can also override the amount of significant digits with the second parameter to `vpa`, but that's not needed in your case.

Here's a quick example:

```
>> syms s
>> A = s + 5/2

A =

s + 5/2

>> vpa(A)

ans =

s + 2.5
```

Comment: Nice! I was trying with `sym/eval`, to no avail

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! To be honest that's what I tried too at first :D

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the initial approximation mode of the numeric literal to decimal mode, where the precision is dictated by [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html), using the [`'d'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#inputarg_flag) flag of the [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) function:

```
>> expr = sym('s') + sym(5/2,'d')

expr =

s + 2.5
```

Comment: Ah, very nice.  I actually stumbled upon that in the documentation just as you wrote this answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah.  I'm pretty sure it's just an upfront conversion to `vpa` under the hood though.

Comment: You're right.  `vpa` actually calls `digits` for each term in the symbolic expression and gives each term up to 32 significant digits.  You can also override this with the second parameter to `vpa`.